# How can I find out which languages GitHub thinks my project is written in?

Tags: github

I can't seem to find any indication in the GitHub UI which languages it thinks my projects are in.

Also, is there a way to suggest a different set of languages for each project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the color bar in the screenshot below:

[image]

FYI: [How does github figure out a project's language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5318580/395857) (answer:  using the [linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist))

Answer (score 2):

To complete Franck Demoncourt's answer and answer the second question:

> Also, is there a way to suggest a different set of languages for each project?

You can use [**Linguist overrides**](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) to change the language of a set of files. This will impact syntax highlighting as well as language statistics. For example, with a `.gitattributes` file you make sure Linguist recognizes all your `.h` files as C++:

```
*.h linguist-language=C++
```